# PHP PDO mysql fetch row by result id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a kind of odd question. Let's say I have an array of numbers like this:

```
$positions = array(1, 2, 5, 9, 25, 68, 130);
```

then I run a database query on a table with lets say 300 records

```
$stmt = dbpdo::$conn->query("SELECT * FROM table"); // 300 rows/records
```

Is there a way I can only fetch certain rows (results) based on my positions array? For example

```
$stmt->fetch(row #1);
$stmt->fetch(row #9);
$stmt->fetch(row #68);
```

Comment: Are those positions values in the table? Because then you can put them in a WHERE clause. If they are random, you can ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7. If they represent some kind of distribution you can use session variables to label every row and then apply a filter like so SET @pos=0;
SELECT @pos:=@pos+1 as row, * FROM table WHERE/HAVING row IN (1, 2, 5). I am not sure if that last one will work

Comment: I have one table that is for positions with values for each position that never change. First based on certain criteria I get the positions I need from that table. I am selecting results from a separate table that will constantly be returned in different order. So there is no key I can associate one table with the other. So I each position I need would be the row result I need from table 2. If that makes any kind of sense.

Comment: Ok, then it seems like the limit 1 offset x is your best bet (good idea Sammitch). However, if size/performance is not an issue, I would just fetch everything into an array and get the rows you need from that. Otherwise, you can look into mysql cursors that would allow you to move on to the next row without the overhead of transmitting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to write your query to minimize the amount of data returned. Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 5, 9, 25, 68, 130)
```

Otherwise the database is going to want to send you 100% of all data in the table on every request rather than just the 7 rows you're interested in.

You can also use `LIMIT 1,$offset` to get a single record `$offset` rows from the beginning of the result set. ***However, this is far less efficient.*** MySQL still computes 100% of the result set and then simply iterates through it until it gets to the Nth record.

Ideally, you also want to restrict your query to only return a finite set of columns rather than `*`. This will reduce the overhead of your application.

#### edit

In response to @serg's suggestion. ***`ORDER BY RAND()` is literally the devil.*** You should never use it unless you are 1,000,000% certain that your entire result set [*disregarding* `LIMIT` clauses, LIMIT has no effect on how bad this is!] will never be larger than a few dozen rows and you're fine with completely throwing away all of your indexes.

Seriously, do not do it.

Comment: Yes I was thinking that too... using the minimum position for the offset and then the max position minus the minimum position for the limit. Was hoping mysql had some magic way  of only selecting certain rows but I guess not. I'll just loop through them and filter out the the rows that don't have a position.